# Bind part of ng-model with scope in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my application i have array of colors and i want to create a list of colors with checkbox.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.colors = ['red','blue','green','yellow'];
});
```

so i create an `ng-repeat` to create a list :

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="c in colors">
  <input type="checkbox" ng ng-true-value="{{c}}" ng-false-value=""/> {{c}}
  </li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

now i need to bind `ng-model` of each checkbox to something like `f.tags.red` or `f.tags.blue` so i change the code to something like this :

```
  <li ng-repeat="c in colors">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="f.col.{{c}}" ng-true-value="{{c}}" ng-false-value=""/> {{c}}
</li>
```

but this make my app broken.so ho to fix this for `ng-model` and `ng-true-value` also i create this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/taveq/2/edit?html,js,output) .
thanks

Comment: Try `ng-model=f.col[c]` instead.

Comment: Thanks,and how about `ng-true-value`

Comment: Ok, so I got it working. First of, you change the model to `f.col[c]`, and the true-value to `c`. Then you need to actually also create the `f` and `f.col` objects on the scope.

Answer (score 2):

There were a few things going wrong here. In general, inside properties of Angular that takes `expressions` (check the docs), you should not use `{{x}}`, but rather just `x` itself. So, you'r `ng-model` should not be `f.col.{{c}}` but rather `f.col.blue` and `f.col.red` etc. Now, in javascript, doing `a.b` and `a['b']` is identical, so in this case, since `c` is a string, the correct model is `f.col[c]`. The same goes for the `true-value`, it should also simply be `c`.

Lastly, to get the example working, you need to actually create the objects maintaining your model (in this case `$scope.f.col`. Working example can be seen here: http://jsbin.com/citupepa/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Here is working demo for selection of colors:
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/huzimesu/1/edit)

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="c in colors">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="f.col[c]" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"/> {{c}}
</li>
```

Selected Colors: {{f.col}}